# How do I clone a div contains multiple input fields more than once?

Tags: jquery, clone

I have read few solutions in here but I still could not figure out why my `div` refuse to clone more than once.

Here is my `html`:

```
<h4 class="ui dividing header">Maklumat Ahli Keluarga</h4>
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
        <div class="ahli_keluarga" id="ahli_keluarga1">
            <div class="field">
                <label>Nama</label>
                   <div class="field">
                   <input type="text" name="shipping[first-name]" placeholder="Nama Penuh">
                   </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum div allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var clone           = $( ".ahli_keluarga:first").clone().append('<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>');

    var x = 1; //initlal div count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max div allowed
            x++; //div increment
            $(wrapper).append(clone); //
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>
```

The cloning works but it only clone the `div` once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
add_button.click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        var clone = $( ".ahli_keluarga:first").clone().append('<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>');
        wrapper.append(clone); //
    }
});

wrapper.on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})
```

});

In your events no need to provide selectors again

```
add_button.click
wrapper.on("click"
```

Edit : I moved the cloning inside the event to clone a new instance not the same instance inserted in the DOM.

I also created a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/hpyzzcj9/

Comment: i want to clone it multiple times.this script only able to clone it once.

Comment: @j.Doe it is working now the reason is we keep on appending the same object and it will not be treated as new in DOM so it will not be inserted.

Comment: thanks ! i get it now and both answers works. thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 3):

You need to clone the nodes every time you click add, otherwise it's just going to reference the element that's already there. Additionally, your `wrapper` is already a jQuery element, so no need to wrap in a `$()`.

Change this line:

```
$(wrapper).append(clone);
```

to

```
wrapper.append(clone.clone());
```

There's a full running snippet below if you want to see it in action.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields      = 10; //maximum div allowed
  var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
  var clone           = $(".ahli_keluarga:first").clone().append('<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>');

  var x = 1; //initlal div count
  $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max div allowed
      x++; //div increment
      wrapper.append(clone.clone()); //
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="ui dividing header">Maklumat Ahli Keluarga</h4>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div class="ahli_keluarga">
    <div class="field">
      <label>Nama</label>
      <div class="field">
        <input type="text" name="shipping[first-name]" placeholder="Nama Penuh">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```